# NestJS share dynamic module instance

Tags: nestjs

I'm struggling a bit with Nest's dynamic modules.
I have a utility service which needs a password to be injected on startup.

```js
@Injectable()
export class CryptoService {

    constructor(
        @Inject("password") private password: string
    ) {}
   ...
}
```

This service is part of a "shared" `CryptoModule`...

```js
@Module({
     providers: [CryptoService]
    ,exports: [CryptoService]
})
export class CryptoModule {

    public static forRoot(password: string): DynamicModule {
        const providers = [{
             provide: "password"
            ,useValue: password
        }];

        return {
             module: CryptoModule
            ,providers: providers
        };
    }
}
```

With "shared" I mean that it's not specific to the current app, so it can be reused in other Nest apps as well.

I import the `CryptoModule` in my `AppModule` like so...

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ...
        ,CryptoModule.forRoot("super-secure-password")
        ,EmailModule
    ]
    ,controllers: [...]
    ,providers: [...]
    ,exports: [CryptoModule]
})
export class AppModule {
    ...
}
```

This works and I can inject the `CryptoService` in my `AppModule` classes/services/controllers.
Now I have a 3rd Module (`EmailModule`) which should be independent from my app, so I can reuse it in other Nest apps as well.
Question now is, how do I import the `CryptoModule` in the `EmailModule` without having to set the password in the `EmailModule`? It should use the password that was passed to the `CryptoModule` in `AppModule`.
I tried importing `CryptoModule` like so...

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ...
        ,CryptoModule
    ]
    ,providers: [EmailService]
    ,exports: [EmailService]
})
export class EmailModule {
    ...
}
```

This code however triggers an exception on startup saying:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CryptoService...

> If password is a provider, is it part of the current CryptoModule?

Is there a best practice of how to achieve this? I could make `EmailModule` dynamic as well and pass in the password, so it can forward it to the `CryptoModule`, but somehow that doesn't feel right.

Thanks!

Comment: You can find the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75755269/8050208

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following (probably there are better ways of doing this)...
Added a static `forChildren()` function to the `CryptoModule`, which is used to initialize the module when being imported by the `EmailModule` (or any other module). The `forRoot()` method stores the password in an Observable, which is used by `forChildren()` to asynchronously retrieve the password. Doing this async is required to defeat the race condition between `forChildren()` and `forRoot()`.

```js
import { firstValueFrom, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
...
@Module({
     providers: [CryptoService]
    ,exports: [CryptoService]
})
export class CryptoModule {
    private static readonly credentialsResolved = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

    public static forRoot(password: string): DynamicModule {
        CryptoModule.credentialsResolved.next(password);
        const providers = [{
             provide: "password"
            ,useValue: password
        }];

        return {
             module: CryptoModule
            ,providers: providers
        };
    }

    public static forChildren(): DynamicModule {
        const providers = [{
            provide: "password"
           ,useFactory: async () => await firstValueFrom(CryptoModule.credentialsResolved)
        }];

        return {
            module: CryptoModule
           ,providers: providers
        };
    }
}
```

Usage in EmailModule:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ...
        ,CryptoModule.forChildren()
    ]
    ,providers: [EmailService]
    ,exports: [EmailService]
})
export class EmailModule {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a more elegant solution? This one works but looks like a crunch...

Comment: @SergeyMell no sorry, haven't dug deeper into this