# How to share dynamic module in NestJS?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a dynamic module EmailModule:

```
@Injectable()
export class EmailSender {}

@Module({})
export class EmailModule {
  static forRoot(options: { smtpHost: string; smtpPassword: string }): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: EmailModule,
      providers: [EmailSender,],
      exports: [EmailSender,],
    };
  }
}
```

There is also MainModule which includes CatModule.

```
@Injectable()
export class CatService {
  constructor(emailSender: EmailSender) {}
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    EmailModule,
  ],
  providers: [CatService,],
  exports: [CatService,],
})
export class CatModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [
    EmailModule.forRoot({
      smtpHost: 'localhost',
      smtpPassword: 'password',
    }),
    CatModule,
  ],
})
export class MainModule {}
```

This code doesn't work, because CatService can't resolve EmailSender. I have to import `EmailModule.forRoot({host, password})` inside CatModule.

However, I do not want to do this. Imagine that I have DogModule, HorseModule, BirdModule, CowModule. I do not want to write this long version with `.forRoot({...})` everywhere. I am searching for a solution which allows me to use `.forRoot({...})` in the main module and simply import `EmailModule` in all submodules.

I am sure that it is possible because this is exactly how nestjs ConfigModule works. If I replace EmailModule by ConfigModule everything works!

```
@Injectable()
export class CatService {
  constructor(configService: ConfigService) {}
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
  ],
  providers: [CatService,],
  exports: [CatService,],
})
export class CatModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '../.env',
    }),
    CatModule,
  ],
})
export class MainModule {}
```

I do not understand why does it work with ConfigModule, but not with EmailModule. What is so special about this module?

**UPDATES:**

I've tried the solution provided in the answers, however, it doesn't work.

```
import {type DynamicModule, Inject, Injectable, Module,} from '@nestjs/common';
import {NestFactory,} from '@nestjs/core';


interface EmailModuleOptions {
  smtpHost: string;
  smtpPassword: string;
}
const EMAIL_MODULE_OPTIONS = 'EMAIL_MODULE_OPTIONS';

@Injectable()
export class EmailSender {
  constructor(
    @Inject(EMAIL_MODULE_OPTIONS)
    private readonly config: EmailModuleOptions) {
    console.log('EmailSender constructor, ', config);
  }

  sendEmail(): void {
    console.log({
      message: 'Meow',
      host: this.config.smtpHost,
      password: this.config.smtpPassword,
    });
  }
}

@Module({ })
export class EmailModule {

  private static emailOptions = {};

  static forRoot(options: EmailModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
    this.emailOptions = options;

    return EmailModule.forFeature();
  }

  static forFeature(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: EmailModule,
      providers: [
        EmailSender,
        {
          provide: EMAIL_MODULE_OPTIONS,
          useValue: EmailModule.emailOptions,
        },
      ],
      exports: [EmailSender,],
    };
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class CatService {
  constructor(private readonly emailSender: EmailSender) {}

  sayHello(): void {
    this.emailSender.sendEmail();
  }
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    EmailModule.forFeature(),
  ],
  providers: [CatService,],
  exports: [CatService,],
})
export class CatModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [
    EmailModule.forRoot({
      smtpHost: 'localhost',
      smtpPassword: 'password',
    }),
    CatModule,
  ],
})
export class MainModule {}

const main = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(MainModule);
  const catService = app.get(CatService);
  catService.sayHello();
};
main();
```

and I have this in the console:

```
[Nest] 30872  - 04/06/2023, 2:46:37 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
EmailSender constructor,  { smtpHost: 'localhost', smtpPassword: 'password' }
EmailSender constructor,  {}
[Nest] 30872  - 04/06/2023, 2:46:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] MainModule dependencies initialized +29ms
[Nest] 30872  - 04/06/2023, 2:46:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] EmailModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 30872  - 04/06/2023, 2:46:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] EmailModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 30872  - 04/06/2023, 2:46:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] CatModule dependencies initialized +0ms
{ message: 'Meow', host: undefined, password: undefined }
```

Seems like nestjs creates 2 instances of the EmailSender and I use one whithout the config.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT on 09/05/2020**

You have 1 easy solution :

- using "global: true" into your Email Config (could be usefull if you want to import this module only once and use it in every modules):

```js
@Injectable()
export class EmailSender {}

@Module({})
export class EmailModule {
  static forRoot(options: { smtpHost: string; smtpPassword: string }): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: EmailModule,
      global: true,
      providers: [EmailSender,],
      exports: [EmailSender,],
    };
  }
}
```

Finally if you really want to implement forRoot and ForFeature you have to implement it like configModule does. But i never did it..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but seems that last 2 options don't work. It creates 2 instances of CatService. One with empty config and another with proper config. When I try to send email, I have an error, because I use the first instance without the config. Could you check my updates above, please?

Comment: You've right it is not working .. I tryed it to fast sorry for the wrong answer. I search but there are not easy answer. You have to implement it like the configModule does but not easy shot..